# active color using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, colors, accordion

please see code bottom, is about the bootstrap accordion, as you can see part of codes where it show on the title section...

```
<dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Manage</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
```

I'm trying to add (icon, text and background COLOR) using css .active and jquery..

please see the same code...

```
      <dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
    <dd class="accordion_content">
    <div class="list-group">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posts</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;comments</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Notifications</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Emails</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sites Infor</a>
</div>
    </dd>
```

in css..

```
.active{
color:blue;
background-color:red;
}
```

and in jquery

```
   jQuery('.accordion dt').click(function() {
         jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down ').closest('dt').next()
         .slideToggle().siblings('.accordion_content').slideUp();

    });

jQuery('.accordion_content').hide();
```

my question is that how can write addiation code to allow change (icon, text and background color) when person click on the title name ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all of your given code works. Remove all `active` class from all the elements and add it to the clicked element.

```
jQuery('.accordion dt').click(function() {
     jQuery(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down ').closest('dt').next()
     .slideToggle().siblings('.accordion_content').slideUp();
    //changes starts here;
    jQuery('.accordion dt').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');

});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('dt').click(function() {

    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down ').closest('dt').next()
      .slideToggle().siblings('.accordion_content').slideUp();
    $('dt').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.accordion_content').hide();
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
<dd class="accordion_content">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posts</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Notifications</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Emails</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sites Infor</a>
  </div>
</dd>
<dt><span><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings</span><i class="accordion_icon fa fa-chevron-up"></i></dt>
<dd class="accordion_content">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Members</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posts</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;comments</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Notifications</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Emails</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action "><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sites Infor</a>
  </div>
</dd>
```

Comment: thanks so much so if i want to add background color of icon from awsome font using .fa class, how can I add that!

Comment: Create css . Add it like a added active class there